# Rewrite user edit page url

Tags: path-aliases

On my Drupal 7 website, I would like a uri like

```
folder/subfolder/preferences
```

to be an alias for the user edit page

```
user/<uid>/edit
```

for all users.  To be precise, when a user navigates to folder/subfolder/preferences, they should be at their own user/"uid"/edit page with the original folder/subfolder/preferences uri in the navigation bar.  If necessary, I wouldn't mind if the aliase contained the uid, so I'd be ok with folder/subfolder/preferences/"uid".

It seems like the pathauto won't do what I want, I'm experimenting with sub-path auto but so far no luck.  If there's a module that can help me do what I want that would be great, but wouldn't mind to do it through a hook if necessary (I haven't figured out how to do this by hooks either).  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Please, consider using [Extended path aliases](http://drupal.org/project/path_alias_xt) or [Sub-pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/subpathauto).

For breadcrumbs you can use [Path Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs) or [Custom breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs).

You also can set active menu item programmaticaly, but I don't like this way:

```
  // Somewhere in menu callback for 'folder/subfolder/preferences' path.
  global $user;
  if (user_is_logged_in()) {
    $path = 'user/' . $user->uid . '/edit';
    menu_set_active_item($path);
    return menu_execute_active_handler($path, FALSE);
  }
```

Maybe someone can improve this code to be more transparent.

*Tip: you often can find related modules in module description or on the right sidebar on Drupal.org. I found these modules on [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) page.*